# request.getAttribute is null when I call it in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

It calls Servlet by click a href.

```
    <li ><a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/ProviderServlet">privilegeManagement</a></li>
```

this code is include in the navigation.jsp which is included in the main.jsp.

then it's my servlet.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProviderDao pd  = new ProviderDao();
    List<ProviderArchives> list = pd.getArchives();
    String str = "chenfeng";
    req.setAttribute("list", list);
    req.setAttribute("hu" , str);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/main.jsp").forward(req,resp);
}
```

then it's my main.jsp.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="com.chenfeng.javabean.ProviderArchives"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ include file="navigation.jsp"%>
    <div>
        <%@ include file="management.jsp"%>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%
             String k = (String)request.getAttribute("hu");
             out.println(k);
      %>
       <c:forEach items="${list}"  var="item">
       <tr> 
        <td>${item.provideID() }</td> 
        <td>${item.GID }</td> 
        <td>${item.Gname }</td> 
        <td>${item.PID }</td> 
        <td>${item.TEL }</td> 
        <td>${item.ADDR }</td>
        <td> 
         <a href="QueryUserByIdServlet?id=${item.provideID }">Modify</a> 
         <a href="DeleteUserServlet?id=${item.provideID }">Delete</a> 
        </td> 
       </tr> 
      </c:forEach> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

then when I run this on server,it shows like this
[image: result]
thank in advance for any help!

Comment: You are never using the attribute `hu`, so why is it even in there?  Have you checked to make sure that the `list` attribute is not null?

Comment: check your server logs I think there must be an exception that you didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Actually,there is no reason for this code.But the eclipse run into problem.The real problem log output after I delete class file in build directory and build it again.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite clear. You set `attribute` of `Request Object` while you're forwarding `Servlet Context Object`. 
Instead of:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/main.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

Write:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/main.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

Comment: it's not the reason,I have used your advice before.And  getServletContext() is get absolute path of project,but req.getRequestDispatcher is relative path.

Comment: @JingHu Then, as Tim said, check your list variable. It might be null.